# JWT Token generates correctly on local/console app but partially/incorrectly after deployment in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy an ASP.Net API interface to return JWT token from Azure Web App.

Code works correctly and I am able to generate JWT Token on Console app locally but after deployment to Azure Web App it fails. Signed credentials use pfx certificate and _audience is a 3rd party endpoint for this purpose.

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _clientId,
            _audience,
            new List<Claim>
             {
                new("jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new("sub", _clientId),
             },
              now,
              now.AddMinutes(expInMinutes),
              _signingCredentials
            );
```

Through debugging I have narrowed it down to the following failing step in Azure Web App.

```
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = jwtHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

In Azure Web App above step will generate an incomplete token with only encoded **Header** and **Payload** values (which match cosole app generated Header and Payload) but missing ecoded text for **Signature**.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i am able to generate JWT token from Azure Web App

**Step-1**:
In controller I added `GenerateToken()`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("generate")]
public ActionResult<string> GenerateToken()
{
    // Replace these values with your actual client ID, audience, and key
    var clientId = "your client ID";
    var audience = " your-audience";
    var key = "your actual key";

    var jwtGenerator = new JwtTokenGenerator(clientId, audience, 60);
    var token = jwtGenerator.GenerateToken(key);

    return Ok(token);
}
```

**Step-2**:
Added the `JwtTokenGenerator` class in my project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace tokenweb.Controllers
{
    public class JwtTokenGenerator
    {
        private readonly string _clientId;
        private readonly string _audience;
        private readonly int _expInMinutes;

        public JwtTokenGenerator(string clientId, string audience, int expInMinutes)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _audience = audience;
            _expInMinutes = expInMinutes;
        }

        public string GenerateToken(string key)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _clientId,
                _audience,
                new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim("sub", _clientId),
                },
                now,
                now.AddMinutes(_expInMinutes),
                new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(key)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            return jwtHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

**Local Deployment**
[image]

**Azure WebApp Deployment(Cloud)**

[image]